# Getting selected value of a UIPickerViewControl in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

How can I get the selected value of a UIPickerViewControl in Swift?

I tried something like this:

```
labelTest.text = Spinner1.selectedRowInComponent(0).description
```

But this only returns the selected index. I need the value.

Anyone who knows how to do this?

Comment: let selectedValue = rolePicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)  gives me a value.  Also, let selectedValue = rolePicker.selectedRowInComponent(0).hashValue   might also give you something of use.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you will have to set the picker view delegate to self and override this function

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
   {
        // use the row to get the selected row from the picker view
        // using the row extract the value from your datasource (array[row])
    }
```

or

you can use this to extract as per your usage

```
var selectedValue = pickerViewContent[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
```

where pickerViewContent is your array of dataSource

Comment: I understand the last method, but how can I retreive my array of dataSource?

Comment: where have you set the datasource for the picker view, you must have set it within the same class .

Comment: i like the high level concept of the first option.  :)

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3:** supose you want the String value of each row selected

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let valueSelected = yourDataSourceArray[row] as String
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

```
let selectedYearPicker = pickerData[yearPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 
print(selectedYearPicker)
```

**Or**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent  component: Int) {
    let yearValueSelected = pickerData[row] as String
    print(yearValueSelected)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers so far presuppose you can easily connect the selected row back to the original data array.  The solution is fairly easy if you can do that, but the question specifically addresses the case where the original array is not readily available.  For instance I have 3 pickers in table cells that expand when one row is tapped, and they show 3 different arrays.

It would save me a lot of trouble if I could simply retrieve the selected text from the picker itself, perhaps in the code for my custom cell, instead of having to figure out which picker, which data array, which row and so on.

If the answer is that you *can't*, that's OK, I'll sort it all out.  But the question is whether there's a shortcut.

Comment: Never mind.  Getting back to the selected row of the picker's input data array was easier than I thought.  No need for a shortcut, even if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is right except for it should include a typecast from String to Int:

```
var selectedValue = pickerViewContent[Int(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0))!]
```