# How can I get the selected value in the real-time, when I'm scrolling the UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uipickerview

[image: This is my prototype]
For example, in this image, when I'm scrolling the UIPickerView to `2012 9 28`, *what I want is that* the text of the black label will change into `2012 9 28` **at the same time** without pressing any buttons like the Done button

I’m using UIPickerView, I can get the selected data before, I can also put the data into label by clicking a Done button, but I **cannot** put the data into the label when I’m scrolling.

and In a general situation,
My question is that when I Scroll the UIPickerView, how can I get the data which is selected **in real time**

could anyone help me ? ObjectiveC solution is OK, Swift solution is better for me, Thank you so much

Comment: I’ve edited the question, if it is better to understand now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting selected value of a UIPickerViewControl in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674399/getting-selected-value-of-a-uipickerviewcontrol-in-swift)

Comment: There is no supported way of doing this (check the [UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate)). For a hackish approach, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7626141/1305067).

Comment: @the4kman What I need is different from your link, I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear if you are using a UIPickerView or a UIDatePicker.

For UIPickerView you need to implement the UIPickerViewDelegate. Make sure that delegate is added to your ViewController declaration and make sure in Storyboard to connect the delegate of the UIPickerView control to your view controller. Then implement this function:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
        didSelectRow row: Int, 
         inComponent component: Int) {

}
```

For UIDatePicker you need to connect the action of the UIDatePicker in Storyboard to an @IBAction function in your view controller or else connect it in code using the addTarget function:

```
myDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.respondToPicker, for: .valueChanged),
```

Comment: I’m using UIPickerView, Thank you for the answer, I’ve implemented **get the data by click a Done button** before, but I can also get the data when I’m **scrolling**, but can’t put data into the Label when I’m scrolling

Comment: Did you put your label update code in the pickerView didSelectRow function? You might need to dispatch it on the MainQueue to see it update correctly.

Comment: I will try it later

Answer (score 0):

Let me suppose that you are using **UIDatePicker**, in that you can control the action using **UIControlEventValueChanged**

Like,

```
datePickerView?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.valueChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

the valueChanged() will be,

```
func valueChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    let selectedDate = datePicker.date as NSDate
    print(selectedDate)
}
```

and if you are using **UIPickerview** then,

**titleForRow**: will gave you scrolling value

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    print("your value")
}
```

and **didSelectRow**: will give you selected value

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
     print("your value")
}
```